# modifying the jdbc.properties file for a Tomcat webapp

Tags: java, oracle, web-applications, tomcat

I am trying to point a Tomcat webapp from one Oracle database to another. To do so, I navigated to the webapps/[my web app]/WEB-INF/classes folder, and I edited the jdbc.properties file so as to change the connection URL, user, and password.

As soon as I did this, the webapp failed to work (it was working before). I end up getting Apache Tomcat error 404 - "The requested resource [my web app] is not available".

I know that the connection URL along with the user/password combo work perfectly fine, as I have tested it in SQL clients. Does anyone know why my webapp failed to work after my modifications? Are there any other modifications that I have to make?

Comment: Have you start/re-start Tomcat after modification?

Comment: How do I do this? I can't access the manager commands via HTTP, simply because the Tomcat app is running on a server to which I only have SSH access. How can I execute the reload, install, list, etc. commands by means other than a browser?

Comment: With SSH to a linux server, you probably can do> service tomcat restart

Comment: you should not to do this, just restarting tomcat using SSH client

Comment: I've restarted Tomcat several times but it doesn't help. I still get the Apache Tomcat error 404 when I open the URL in a browser.

Comment: Check the catalina logs. It could give you clues why the web app failed to load.